# Parse JSON data with illegal tokens using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to parse some JSON data using jQuery and I'm having trouble trying 'target' certain entries because some of the JSON entries have illegal characters (such as :) and jQuery errors when these are fetched, with the message *"Unexpected token : "*.

Here is my jQuery script, where the first appendage gets the data without any errors *('j.profileInfo.profileName')* and the second line is causing the issue *('j.totalsForAllResults.ga:visitors')*.

```
var myjson = '{
    "itemsPerPage": 50,
    "totalResults": 1,
    "profileInfo": {
        "profileId": "12345678"
    },
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "ga:visitors": "100",
        "ga:newVisits": "30"
    }
}';

var j = $.parseJSON(myjson);

$("body").append("<h2>" + j.profileInfo.profileName + "</h2>");
$("body").append("<p>" + j.totalsForAllResults.ga:visitors + "</p>");
```

I'm fetching the json data from the Google API so I can't edit the JSON unfortunately. Is there another way I can target the data, perhaps something the long the lines of j.totalsForAllResults[0] so that I don't need to put the : in? Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) may be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) in that case instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation)

```
j.totalsForAllResults['ga:visitors']
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/suZ5h/)